# indexOf() skipped repeated element javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the values of odd positions in the array below but it skipped 7, what could be wrong, please?

```
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

const validateCred = (serialDigits)=>{
  //let sum = 0;
  for (let i = serialDigits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    let currentDigit = serialDigits[i];
    
    if( serialDigits.indexOf(currentDigit) % 2 === 1){
      console.log(currentDigit)
        };
    }
}

console.log(validateCred(valid1));
// 0 6 0 0 6 3 4
```

Comment: `indexOf` finds the first matching item. Just use `i` which is already the index of the current item in the array.

Comment: @VLAZ I used `i` and it checked the values rather than the position in the array.

Comment: This is impossible. You declare `i` as the index in your loop. It starts from the last index of the array and goes on to the first (to zero). It's not possible for `i` to be the value of that index. That is `currentDigit`.

Comment: Simplest way would be to start your for loop at 1 and then keep adding 2, making the loop only iterate over odd indexes. ```for ( let i=1 ; i < serialDigits.length ; i=i+2 ){ console.log( serialDigits[ i ] ); }```. Seems like you're over-complicating the function. Or is there a particular reason you want to print the data in reverse?

Comment: Thank you guys for the clearance, this journey I must, is not an easy one. Just a month and I am feeling overwhelmed. Nevertheless, I ain't quitting.
Thank you guys for the clearance, this journey I must, is not an easy one. Just a month and I am feeling overwhelmed. Nevertheless, I ain't quitting.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if( serialDigits.indexOf(currentDigit) % 2 === 1){
```

Is not a good line because indexOf find the first occurrence in the array, therefore, do not fulfil your need. just use the variable i instead:

```
if (i % 2 === 1) {
```

Similarly, if you want to print the even indexes, you can use this code:

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

const validateCred = (serialDigits) => {
  //let sum = 0;
  for (let i = serialDigits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let currentDigit = serialDigits[i];

    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      console.log(currentDigit);
    };
  }
}

validateCred(valid1);
// 0 6 0 0 7 6 3 4
```

Comment: I tried `if( i % 2 === 1){` and it printed `15 13 11 9 7 5 3 1`. What I want to print is `0 6 0 0 7 6 3 4` while going through the array. Thank you.

Comment: So you have to be precise in your question. You probably want even indexes, and not odd. Also, if you replace only the line I gave you, it will print the value of the position, and not the position. I have your code running on my computer. Please, check your code.

Comment: Thank you guys for the clearance, this journey I must, is not an easy one. Just a month and I am feeling overwhelmed. Nevertheless, I ain't quiting.